# How can I add multiple properties with the same name to an object?

Tags: javascript, object

Say I have an object that looks something like this:

[image: sample object view in chrome tools]

I want to gain the ability to add multiple `CopyTo` property sections that hold similar data. However, I'm not sure if this is allowed under normal Javascript behavior. What's the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: Make CopyTo an array. And then add as many of the CopyTo Objects to that array as you desire.

Comment: You cannot. Property keys are unique.

Comment: Follow TravisJ 's advice. You might want to look up the term 'multimap', too.

Comment: Please do not post images, not every one can view them and text is much more accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

property names in javascript must be unique!

you want, e.g., an array of "property section" objects:

```
{
  ...
  "copyTo" : [
    {
      // property section 1
    },
    {
      // property section 2, etc.
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```